# low speed of xmlhttprequest on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I work on a site. recently it does not have a stable speed.
at the same time, loading a page could have a different speed. usually, it has a low speed at the beginning of loading a page. I monitor HTTP request via web sniffer extension. I realized the low-speed appear on `xmlhttprequest`.
I down know how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHTTPREQUEST (a.k.a AJAX) is not synchronous request and can't affect your website response and loading speed.

You need to use Monitoring plugins which monitors backend side, not frontend.

For example [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) can help you with this.